# Can't disable touchpad while typing

Tags: 20.04, touchpad

I want to disable the touchpad while typing, but can't seem to do it. The gnome setting is set to true, but it does nothing.

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad disable-while-typing
true

$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep -i touchpad
N: Name="ELAN1201:00 0 4F3:3098 Touchpad"
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, this was caused by the touchpad/keyboard being incorrectly registered as external devices. The disabling when typing behaviour is only for internal input devices.

To fix it I did the following:

Make sure `libinput-tools` is installed, `sudo apt install libinput-tools`

Then `sudo libinput list-devices`

This gives you a list of devices from `libinput`, such as keyboards and touchpads

You'll want to take note of the `Kernel` item for your keyboard and touchpad. It may be a bit tricky to figure out which ones you need, I had 2 entries for my keyboard, an entry for my touchpad, and an entry for mouse, while not having a mouse plugged in.

Then for each of the `Kernel` paths, run the following

`sudo libinput quirks list /dev/input/event7` (replacing the path)

Take note of the devices where this command DOES NOT output `AttrKeyboardIntegration=internal`. If all devices output this, this solution will not work.

Finally, create a file `/etc/libinput/local-overrides.quirks`

```
[Name of overwrite, doesn't matter much]
MatchUdevType=keyboard
MatchName=NAME OF DEVICE
AttrKeyboardIntegration=internal
```

Where `MatchName` is equal to the `Device` item of `sudo libinput list-devices`

`MatchUdevType` should be the type of device. `keyboard`, `touchpad` & `mouse` did the trick for me.

Add a separate entry for each device that did not output `AttrKeyboardIntegration=internal` previously

Comment: best answer I've seen anywhere. One clarification for tiny-brained folk (like me!):  "NAME OF DEVICE" should be the value from the "Device:" line (e.g. "DLL07BE:01 06CB:7A13 Touchpad") NOT the device ID (e.g. "/dev/input/event17")